# SharePoint 2010 and ASHX Handler

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to get a webpart deployed and using a Silverlight webpart with an upload control inside. I am however, receiving the following error in the application log when I access my ashx.

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: HttpParseException 
Exception message: Could not create type 'FileUploadSP.UploadHandler'.
```

I've got an UploadHandler.cs file with the following code:

```
namespace FileUploadSP
{
public class UploadHandler : RadUploadHandler 
{
    public override void ProcessStream()
    {
        base.ProcessStream();

        if (this.IsFinalFileRequest())
        {
            string filename = this.Request.Form["RadUAG_fileName"];
            string fullPath = @"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\FileUploadSP\FileTemp\";
            SPContext.Current.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullPath + filename, FileMode.Open);
            SPContext.Current.Web.Files.Add("/UploadLibrary/" + filename, fs, true);
            fs.Close();
            File.Delete(fullPath + filename);
        }

    }
}
```

}

And I have the following in my .ashx file:

> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
>   <%@ Assembly Name="FileUploadSP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c8e2c3ef53023ee" %>
>   <%@ WebHandler Language="C#"  Class="FileUploadSP.UploadHandler" %>

I cannot get the .ashx to work as I expected to. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll probably get a better response over at [sharepoint.se]

Comment: Thanks, I'll post it over there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check your assembly is in the web.config safe list, and has been deployed to the GAC, with an iis reset.

Ashx can be blocked (and unblocked in central admin), but I guess from your error this is not the case.

Comment: I will check on that tomorrow morning, didn't think about the web.config.

Comment: So I was finally able to get a detailed error.

Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Windows.RadUploadHandler, Version=2011.2.712.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Need to figure out what files need to be GAC'd from there I guess. And safe controls added as well.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was the blocked file types under central admin -> security.
ASHX was on the no-no list.